# Referencing elements id - backbone.js, jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jquery-autocomplete

The autocomplete works fine and binds to all the input fields.  However if there is an error I need to reference the id of the input so I can display the appropriate error message, can anyone point me in the right direction?  Referencing this is the page and referencing $(this) is undefined.

```
            render: function() {
                this.$(".inputClass").autocomplete({ // add book dialog
                    source: function(request, response ) {
                         $.ajax({
                             url: someurl + request.term,
                             dataType: "json",
                             global: false, // disable loadingScreen
                             success: function(json) {
                                 books = json.data.list;
                                 response( $.map( i, function( item ) {
                                     return {
                                         test: item.test,
                                     };
                                 }));
                             },
                             error: function(json) {
                                //get element id and apply error class
                             } // error
                         }); // ajax
                    }, // source
                    minLength:1
                 });
      return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword in Javascript changes its context inside a function.  To get around this you can save a reference to the original context (call it *"that"* or *"self"* by convention).

```
render: function() { 
    var that = this;

    // ...

    error: function(json() {
        that.$el.addClass("error");
    }
```

Comment: Yes...but actually it needs to be saved in the source callback function, not in the render where you have it.

Comment: @ToddGibson why, shouldn't any inner function definitions be able to access `that`?

Comment: It can be accessed, but it will be the wrong thing.  I think he wants know the specific element that the ajax failed on.